# D3 Bar Chart with Tooltip on X-Axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am using a D3 bar chart.  I can show the tooltip when the mouse is over the bar (from http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579).  However, in some of my charts, the Y range is large, with some having a large value and some small, with the result that some of the bar charts have essentially 0 height.  So, I might have points ('a', 10245), and ('b', 32).  That '32' is still important, but I can't mouse over the bar because it is too small.

How can I add the same tooltip to the x-axis, so I can show a tip that says 'b:32'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind the data and set up events:

```
   d3.selectAll('.x .tick')
    .data(data)
    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jZKgo2fn2enSy4zm7QFY?p=preview).